# What is happening when Fiddler records two sockets in X-ServerSocket

Tags: sockets, fiddler

I've been running into some unexpected and strangely consistent HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure, and when looking into the response I see a the X-ServerSocket value to be two values:

```
X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE ServerPipe#1321REUSE ServerPipe#384*NEW*
```

This would seem to imply that the two server sockets were used for the connection, this seems bizarre.  Are there conditions where this should happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 values in that X-SERVERSOCKET entry, to be read as

```
REUSE ServerPipe#1321
REUSE ServerPipe#384
*NEW*
```

So during the course of the request, fiddler attempted to reuse an already established 1321, which failed over, so then 384 was used, and finally a new socket was created, and this one also did not get a valid response.

This pattern clearly indicates that fiddler was unable to get a response after trying numerous times.  To dig into what is going wrong you'll need to look into the network outside of fiddler.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/x-serversocket-multiple-server-sockets#r5wedUgIuk2nyzJDBBzzVQ